# nativescript modal dialog transparency

Tags: ios, dialog, nativescript

I try to create a custom dialog with nativescript using this link https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/modal-page.html
All work great. But I don't know how to make the modal dialog transparent. The property backgroundcolor doesn't works with ios
Any help will be fine

Answer (score 4):

Apple recommends that you don't make modals transparent, see this issue on nativescript's issue tracker: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2086#issuecomment-220629191

Nativescript's built-in modal is always fullscreen on iOS and cannot be transparent.

BUT you can workaround that if you (like us) need to.

Here is how we did it with nativescript-angular:
First inject Page in the modal-component. 
On iOS override the function `_showNativeModalView` on the page-object like this:

```
import { Page } from 'ui/page';
const pageCommon = require('ui/page/page-common').Page;
import { Color } from 'color';
import * as utils from 'utils/utils';
```

...... 
in the constructor:

```
if (page.ios) {
  // iOS by default won't let us have a transparent background on a modal
  // Ugly workaround from: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript/issues/2086#issuecomment-221956483
  page.backgroundColor = new Color(50, 0, 0, 0);

  (<any>page)._showNativeModalView = function(parent, context, closeCallback, fullscreen) {
    pageCommon.prototype._showNativeModalView.call(this, parent, context, closeCallback, fullscreen);
    let that = this;

    this._modalParent = parent;
    if (!parent.ios.view.window) {
        throw new Error('Parent page is not part of the window hierarchy. Close the current modal page before showing another one!');
    }

    if (fullscreen) {
      this._ios.modalPresentationStyle = 0;
    } else {
      this._ios.modalPresentationStyle = 2;
      this._UIModalPresentationFormSheet = true;
    }

    pageCommon.prototype._raiseShowingModallyEvent.call(this);

    this._ios.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true;
    this._ios.definesPresentationContext = true;
    this._ios.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
    this._ios.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    this._ios.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;

    parent.ios.presentViewControllerAnimatedCompletion(this._ios, utils.ios.MajorVersion >= 9, function completion() {
      that._ios.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
      that._raiseShownModallyEvent(parent, context, closeCallback);
    });
  };
}
```

You could also override that prototype of Page, but I think it's much cleaner to override it on the instance of Page instead.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know you could inject the page like that then adjust it's transparency. 

Newb question - typescript is complaining about UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen, UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve, UIColor, and UIModalPresentationCurrentContext... how do I import those?

Comment: You don't import them, they're global native values. You can use "declare var UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;" to remove the warning.